# how to disable cairo-dock opened application effect?

Tags: icons, cairo-dock, effects

When an application is opened but not focused, it keeps an effect running, the rotation effect.

I want it to have no effect, but I am not being able to find where to configure it.

I looked at simple and advanced cairo-dock options, many... many times. I searched for "effect" to no avail. I looked at it long ago too, a few years, and I completely disabled effects because of that, but now I want to re-enable and I am having the same problem again.

So where can I find the effect configuration for just opened application but not focused? It is not at "animated icons" section, where should be the right place for it to be.

Answer (score 2):

I found this: `~/.config/cairo-dock/current_theme/cairo-dock.conf` "animation on demands attention=rotate"

It is at: behavior/taskbar/interaction.

just select the blank (empty first item) option at it will be disabled for good!